# can't unset WWW-Authenticate header in apache 2.2 with auth_kerb_module

Tags: apache, header, kerberos

I have an apache 2.2 that use auth_kerb_module to enable AuthType Kerberos. 
Not all users use a browser with NTLM enabled. that's why we have to set *KrbMethodK5Passwd* to on (it ask for user and password in a popup in firefox, for example). 
In the other hand this site publish documents via webdav, and microsoft office use ADAL to authenticate (we need to edit documents from office to webdav this webdav repository). Because we don't have Oauth, we need to set the response header WWW-Authenticate  to Negotiate when the request has Authorization header set to Bearer
. 
This is the directives we use

```
SetEnvIf Authorization "Bearer" ISADAL
Header always set WWW-Authenticate Negotiate env=ISADAL
```

The directive seems to work BUT apache returns two headers

```
WWW-Authenticate:  Negotiate Basic realm="
WWW-Authenticate:  Negotiate
```

If we set `KrbMethodK5Passwd` to off, `WWW-Authenticate:  Negotiate Basic realm="` dissapears.

I think that `KrbMethodK5Passwd` set `Negotiate Basic realm="` AFTER the `header set` directive applies. Do you think this could be the problem?

Is there any way to edit the header after `KrbMethodK5Passwd on` applies to have only one  WWW-Authenticate header?

Thank you !!!

Comment: Hi!
Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Why don't you use Apache 2.4 with state-of-the-art [mod_auth_gssapi](https://github.com/modauthgssapi/mod_auth_gssapi)?

Comment: Hi Michael!
Unfortunately this is not an option in my case, can't upgrade apache. Have you ever faced a problem like this?
Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: I used with Apache 2.2 lha/mod_spnego from GitHub.